# Not able to find KeyStore (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hello guys I have started a new project and its a firebase project I need SHA-1 and SHA-256 Keys for authentication before I was able to find in gradle tools but am not able to find here. I have even generated a signed build but still am not able to find those keys. I hope these are necessary information for my question.

[image: This is what it shows]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current Android Studio version , for getting SHA-1 and SHA-26 you can do following :

Step 1 : Click on Execute Gradle Task Icon (The Elephant Icon)

[image]

and then Step 2 :
type command

```
gradlew signingReport
```

[image]

and post gradle sync you will get the certificates in the Build section

You can get SHA26 by using keytools using cmd and the command below.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Well I did got my SHA-1 Certificate but how to get SHA-256?

Comment: And off-topic on what project are you working on sounds intresting :)

Comment: That is just an experimental project

Comment: Well keytool is not working for me I dont know why

Comment: I got both SHA 1 and SHA 256 with the above method Thank you so much